# Prolog Unification with not()

Tags: prolog, unification, prolog-dif

I am just learning prolog and there is a thing I can't get my head over.

Suppose I have the following program

```
value(v).

a(X) :- not(value(X)).
```

So `a(v).` gives me false, as `value(v)` can be proved correct.

`a(w)` gives me true, as there is no fact `value(w)`, therefore, even when trying, it can't be proved correct.

In my understanding, requesting `a(X).` should give me the first possible value that makes `value(X)` unproveable. There should be an infinite amount of possibilities, as only `value(v)` is correct.

But why does Prolog keep answering `false`?

Comment: It depends on how you view ***falsification***, what is false? How do you prove that something is false? One view of it is that *Everything that is not provable is false*, which is a view where you imagine that you live in a world where everything that is ***true*** is provable (which is debatable ofcourse). In prolog the  `\+` operator works with negation as failure semantics, which was what I tried to describe above. Hope that gives some clues.

Comment: Yes, If we define false as not proveable, then Prolog could achieve the goal by providing examples that it is unable to prove correct?

Comment: But I guess the problem is that Prolog is always looking to make things **true**, and in this case, we would basically reverse the engine?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, please use the ISO predicate `(\+)/1` *instead* of `not/1`.

Second, please don't use `(\+)/1` to denote *disequality* of terms: `(\+)/1` is **incomplete** in Prolog, and thus not logically sound. It is *not* logical *negation*, but rather denotes "not provable".

In your case: `?- value(X).` succeeds, so it is provable, so `?- \+ value(X).` **fails although there are instantiations that make the query succeed**.

In particular, `?- \+ value(a).` **succeeds**.

So we have:

```
?-        \+ value(V).
false.
```

But a **more specific** query succeeds:

```
?- V = a, \+ value(V).
V = a.
```

This obviously runs counter to logical properties we expect from pure relations. See [logical-purity](/questions/tagged/logical-purity).

To denote *disequality* of terms, use **`dif/2`**. If your Prolog system does not support `dif/2`, ask for its inclusion, or use `iso_dif/2` as a safe approximation that is logically sound. See **[prolog-dif](/questions/tagged/prolog-dif)** for more information.

Comment: Alright, I understand. So in order to achieve my desired functionality, Prolog would need to come up with an unproveable example which it is unable to by design. 

So basically, one could implement this in Prolog (although probably not desireable) and get the behaviour I mentioned? Or am I missing some basic logic concept?

Comment: In your case, simply use `dif/2` or other constraints to express disequality: `dif(X, v)` states that `X` is **different** from the atom `v`. This succeeds, leaving the *residual goal* as long as the goal is not known to hold. For other domains, there are analoguous constraints. For example, `X #\= 3` states that `X` is an **integer** different from 3.

Answer (score 1):

Prolog operates under "closed world assumption" – it only knows what we told it about. In particular, we've told it *nothing* about no `w`, `u`, or any other stuff, so how could it produce them to us? And why should `w` come before `u`, and not vice versa?

The only thing sensible *could* be to produce `(X, dif(X,v))`, but it would be the answer to a *different* question, namely, **"how to make `a(X)` provable?"**, not the one Prolog is actually answering, namely **"is `a(X)` provable?"**.

To ease up your cognitive burden, rename the Prolog prompt's replies in your head from `true` to `Yes`, and from `false` to `No`.

`Yes` would mean Prolog telling us "yes, I could prove it!", and `No` – "no, I couldn't prove it."

Also <s>rename "not" to</s> read `\+` as `not_provable`, mentally.